# Delimiting submatrices in a Jordan Canonical form

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I would like to draw this matrix using LaTeX.
I've seen solutions using the `array` environment, but, as you can notice from the picture, the lines don't go all the way through, so some of them aren't functioning answers.

Perhaps using TikZ?

Thank you all.

[image: Jordan Canonical form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With judicious use of `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
2 & 1 & \?0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 &   0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{1-5}
0 & 0 & \?0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \?0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{4-6}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & \?0 & \?3 & 0 \\
\cline{6-7}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 &   0 & \?0 & 3
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\?` command is locally defined just to ease input (and reading).

[image]

With full borders (`\|` is locally redefined, again for ease of input).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\|}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#1}}
\left(\,\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\cline{1-3}
\|2 & 1 & \?0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\|0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\|0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{1-5}
0 & 0 & \?0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \?0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{4-6}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & \?0 & \?3 & 0 \\
\cline{6-7}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 &   0 & \?0 & \?3 \\
\cline{7-7}
\end{array}\,\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Possibly more appealing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$0$}
\settoheight{\dimen2}{$0$}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{%
  >{\vrule width 0pt height \dimexpr\dimen2+\arraycolsep\relax depth \arraycolsep}
  w{c}{\dimen0}
}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\|}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#1}}
\left(\,\begin{array}{CCCCCCC}
\cline{1-3}
\|2 & 1 & \?0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\|0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\|0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{1-5}
0 & 0 & \?0 & 2 & \?1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \?0 & 0 & \?2 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{4-6}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 & \?0 & \?3 & 0 \\
\cline{6-7}
0 & 0 &   0 & 0 &   0 & \?0 & \?3 \\
\cline{7-7}
\end{array}\,\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `nicematrix`

[image]

If you want to change the style of the lines, you can add `\usepackage{tikz}` and then you can add any TikZ options to the `borders` options, e.g., `tikz={dashed,red}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\Block[borders={bottom,right}]{3-3}{}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \Block[borders={bottom,right,top,left}]{2-2}{} 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block[borders={bottom,right,top,left}]{1-1}{} 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Block[borders={top,left}]{1-1}{}3\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\Block[borders={bottom,right,top,left}]`, it's also possible to write `\Block[draw]` :-)